# Removing element by value from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following problem:

**If** user selects any of `Toyota`, `Mazda`, and `Nissan` **Then** remove `All` from `makeArr` array if exist 
and 
**If** user selects `All` **Then** remove any of `Toyota`, `Mazda`, and `Nissan` from `makeArr` array if they exist

I tried to use this code

```
makeArr.splice($.inArray("All", makeArr), 1);
```

in the `else` part but it is not working!

```js
var makeArr = [];
$(".btn-primary").on("click", function() {
  let make = $(this).data('make');
  if (make === "All") {
    var idx = $.inArray(make, makeArr);
    if (idx == -1) {
      makeArr.push(make);
    } else {
      makeArr.splice(idx, 1);
    }
  } else {
   // makeArr.splice($.inArray("All", makeArr), 1);
    var idx = $.inArray(make, makeArr);
    if (idx == -1) {
      makeArr.push(make);
    } else {
      makeArr.splice(idx, 1);
    }
  }
  console.log(makeArr);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container p-2">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-make="Toyota">Toyota</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-make="Mazda">Mazda</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-make="Nissan">Nissan</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-make="All">All</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `makeArr.splice($.inArray("All", makeArr), 1);`  if "All" doesn't exists, then inArray returns -1 and it return the last element from the array. see `makeArr.splice(-1, 1);`, So, you should check before All element existing or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that when you select `All`, you're not checking if there are any other models in the array already. It's simplest in that case just to check for `All` in the array, and if it is there, empty the array, otherwise set it to `['All']`. Likewise, when a specific model is selected, you need to remove `'All'` from the array if it is in there before adding/removing the selected model.

```js
var makeArr = [];
$(".btn-primary").on("click", function() {
  let make = $(this).data('make');
  if (make === "All") {
    idx = makeArr.indexOf('All');
    makeArr = idx == -1 ? ['All'] : [];
  } else {
    idx = makeArr.indexOf('All');
    if (idx != -1) {
      makeArr.splice(idx, 1)
    }
    idx = makeArr.indexOf(make);
    if (idx != -1) {
      makeArr.splice(idx, 1)
    } else {
      makeArr.push(make);
    }
  }
  console.log(makeArr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container p-2">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-make="Toyota">Toyota</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-make="Mazda">Mazda</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-make="Nissan">Nissan</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-make="All">All</button>
  </div>
</div>
```